# config.ts only returns the first object in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js, config

I have this config.ts file:

```
const config = {
  staging:{
    baseUrl: 'someUrls/stag',
    authEndpointUrl: '',
    pubnubEndpointUrl: ''
  },
  development: {
    baseUrl: 'someUrl/dev',
    authEndpointUrl: '',
    pubnubEndpointUrl: ''
  },
  production: {
    baseUrl: 'someUrl/prod',
    authEndpointUrl: '',
    pubnubEndpointUrl: ''
  }
}

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV ;

module.exports = config[nodeEnv]
```

and this is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
import config from './config.ts';

.
.
.

  env:{
    config
  },
.
.
.
```

in my app if I use `process.env.config.baseUrl` it only returns the first object's `baseUrl`: `'someUrls/stag'. If I change the position of` staging`and`development`in my`config.ts`it returns`baseUrl: 'someUrl/dev'`(again the first object). How can I grab the baseUrl from different objects that I have like`production`?

I tried `process.env.config.production.baseUrl` but it returns null! How can I access different objects in my `config.ts` file?